# I can't get data open weather map

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know why but keeps telling me error 400 when it tries to fetch data from open weather map

even i tried to change the api key and tried to change the code it self but it didn't work

so i want to know why this happening and i want to know the solution for this problem

```
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

const apiKey = '*****53a8**************';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  double lontitude;
  double latitude;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getLocation();
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future getLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();
    latitude = location.latitude;
    lontitude = location.lontitude;
  }

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$lontitude&appid=$apiKey'),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      var temperature = jsonDecode(data)['main']['temp'];
      print(temperature);

      var condition = jsonDecode(data)['weather'][0]['id'];
      print(condition);

      var city = jsonDecode(data)['name'];
      print(city);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, never post/share/etc private information like API KEYs, that could create a major problem and limitations into that service account. I edited to avoid problems.

Comment: Of course, the original version is still in the history. I recommend that you immediately change your apiKey, or else delete this question and repost a new one without a visible key.

Answer (score 0):

Just typing in that URL in a browser and substituting longitude, latitude, and apiKey with values works just fine for me.
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50,123123&lon=13.123123&appid=************** // add private key

OUTPUT:

```json
{"coord":{"lon":13.1231,"lat":50.1231},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":281.16,"feels_like":279.56,"temp_min":279.08,"temp_max":283.95,"pressure":1023,"humidity":79},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":2.57,"deg":250},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1632954450,"sys":{"type":2,"id":47765,"country":"CZ","sunrise":1632978356,"sunset":1633020533},"timezone":7200,"id":3061350,"name":"Žlutice","cod":200}
```

You should check the format of the things that get substituted by your code.

Comment: the answer was edited to remove private information. API Keys should not be shared publicly

Comment: Thnx for the support , I'm still learning so i replaced the lon, lat, and the api key and i worked but know  i don't know where is the error so thank you for the solution.

Comment: can you send your code plz?